# LOG: server process (PID 11748) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault

Tags: postgresql, crash, fedora, segmentation-fault

I am using Postgres-8.3.7 on fedora core 2 linux box. And Postgres service is crashing.
When I restart the system, it is working fine for some time. At some random time it is crashing again.

What could be the possible reasons for this segfaults which are random?

```
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  server process (PID 11748) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2010-05-24 13:28:06 PDT
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
```

Comment: I'm sure you realise you'll get better service if you use the appropriate Postgres [support lists](http://archives.postgresql.org/). My recommendation is to start with the ["general"](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/) list and eventually the ["bugs"](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/) list.

Answer (score 2):

A little too specific, few details - and perhaps more appropiate to serverfault.com , or the postgresql mailing lists.

Some random suggestions:

- VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE ?
- Can't you upgrade to the last version ?
- Some special circumnstances when this happens ? Disk nearly full ? High load ? Nothing suspicious in the OS logs ( /var/log/message ) ?
- Can't you raise the log level of postgresql to log the queries and see if this is related to some particular query (e.g. function)?

Postgresql has a very responsive developers [community](http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/).

Comment: Hi Leonbloy,
Thanks for your reply,
As you said I tried in postgres forums and found out that the possible reason could be hardware/RAM failure. And here in this case there is some problem with mounting the system.